# Is this homebrew creature well balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew

I have created an homebrew creature. I would like to know if it could be a resonable fight for a level 8 team (an elf druid, a human barbarian, a human warrior, a ranger goblin). Have I used too many condition immunities? Thank you.

Is the damage per round too high for a CR 12?

---

---

Name: Poisonous Spherimorph

Large Ooze, unaligned

---

**AC** 15

**HP** 210 (20d10+100)

**Speed** 30ft., climb 30ft.

**STR** 18 (+4)

**DEX** 10 (+0)

**CON** 20 (+5)

**INT** 1 (-5)

**WIS** 10 (+0)

**CHA** 1 (-5)

**Saving Throws**: Wisdom +4

**Skills**: Stealth +4, Perception +4

**Damage Resistances**: bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from non magical weapons

**Damage Immunities**: psychic, poison

**Condition Immunities**: prone, exhausted, unconscious, poisoned, grappled, deafened, blinded, charmed, frightened, restrained

**Senses**: blindsight 18m., passive Perception 14

**Languages**: --

**Challenge** 12 (8,400 XP)

---

**Features**

---

**Amorphous.** The creature can move through a space as narrow as 1 inch wide without squeezing.

**False appearance.** As long as the creature remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from a puddle of water.

**Spider climb.** The creature has the ability to move up, down, and across vertical surfaces and upside down along ceilings, without needing to make an ability check.

---

**Actions**

---

**Multiattack**. The Poisonous Spherimorph makes two attacks: one with Pillar and one with Press.

**Pillar.** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +8 to hit, reach 5ft., one target. *Hit* 16 (3d8 + 4) bludgeoning damage plus 15 (3d10) poison damage. The target when hit must succeed on a DC 17 Constitution saving throw or become poisoned. If the target is already poisoned, no saving throw is made.

**Press.** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +8 to hit, reach 20ft., multiple targets. *Hit* 8 (1d8 + 4) bludgeoning damage plus 5 (1d10) poison damage. The target when hit must succeed on a DC 17 Constitution saving throw or become poisoned. If the target is already poisoned, no saving throw is made.

[image]

Comment: Having the image is fine, but please transcribe the plain text for us.  Not everyone can see image posts, so having the text of your homebrew is essential for making your post accessible to all.

Comment: I can understand if you like meters better than feet, but I fear most of us will be more confused than anything else with the values since all the rulebooks etc. use feet.

Comment: I have Edited my question.

Comment: Did you do your own CR calculations using the rules in the book that we can check against?

Comment: Yes, I followed step by step the DM guide.

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 Please answer in answers, comments are for clarification.

Comment: Reminder to everyone that feedback about the asker's creature is an answer, and as such belongs in an answer post rather than in a comment.

Comment: Is this a fight of 4 v 1 or will there be minions supporting this monster?

Comment: It's 4 vs 1, without minions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The stats seem right-ish.

Damage from pillar is 17.5 + 16.5 = 34.  Damage from press is (8.5 + 5.5) * 2 = 28.  Total damage is 62.

Your monster has AC 15, HP 210, attack bonus +8, and damage 62.

The DMG guidelines say that a CR 12 monster should have AC 17, HP 240, attack bonus +8, damage 77.

But [monster manual on a business card](https://www.blogofholding.com/?p=7338), which reflects stats closer to what monsters actually use, says that a CR 12 monster should have AC 15, HP 180, attack bonus +8, damage 60.

This is pretty close.

#### Whether the resistances are appropriate will depend on your party.

Is your eighth-level group running around with nonmagical weapons?  That would be a bit unusual for a group at that level.  If so, you should use a monster with fewer hit points, since all your characters' attacks will deal half damage.

If your group has magic weapons (or relies on spell attacks, in the case of the druid), then the resistance to nonmagical weapons doesn't matter.

The other resistances and immunities are fine, and are appropriate for an ooze-type monster.

#### CR12 seems appropriate

I went to Kobold Fight Club and told it you had four level-eight characters and they were fighting a CR12 monster.  It told me the encounter was just on the edge of "Deadly", which is probably what you were shooting for.

#### Think more about the poison

Both of your monster's attacks say "the target must succeed on a hard save or become poisoned".

How long does the target remained poisoned?  One round?  One minute?  Until they short rest?  Forever?

Being poisoned is pretty bad because it gives disadvantage to all attacks.  With your monster's AC 15, this will make it quite difficult to hit.  My advice is to make the poison have a short duration, like "until the end of their next turn", so that this isn't crippling for your group's melee attackers.

Comment: Alternatively if the party knows about the long-term poison (say an  hour or something) ahead of time, it would be a good opportunity for the druid to prepare *lesser restoration*.

Comment: I don't think it is viable for the druid to cast *lesser restoration* during combat. 
 This requires an action; it requires entering the ooze's threatened area and being hit unnecessarily by *press*; and it is likely to be wasted since the condition will be reapplied fairly quickly by the ooze's next attack.